# How to create RSA private key with passphrase in Go?

Tags: go, cryptography, rsa

How to create RSA private key with passphrase in Go?

I read the documentation for the [`crypto`](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto) package but I was unable to piece together a solution from it.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#GenerateKey

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First step, generate a private key.
Second step, convert it to PEM format. Third step, encrypt the PEM.

All can be done using Golang's standard library, which is very complete. The code is nothing difficult so I put it here. All there is to it is to know which functions to use.

```
import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/pem"
)

func PrivateKeyToEncryptedPEM(bits int, pwd string) ([]byte, error) {
    // Generate the key of length bits
    key, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, bits)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Convert it to pem
    block := &pem.Block{
        Type:  "RSA PRIVATE KEY",
        Bytes: x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey(key),
    }

    // Encrypt the pem
    if pwd != "" {
        block, err = x509.EncryptPEMBlock(rand.Reader, block.Type, block.Bytes, []byte(pwd), x509.PEMCipherAES256)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }

    return pem.EncodeToMemory(block), nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had problems with EncryptPEMBlock. Language know very badly. I do not know about methods of block. Thanks again, is now understood. _sory for my english_